# Find the number Ramu missed given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image]

Adding consecutive natural numbers can be of the form n+(n+1)+(n+2)....(n+n-1)

It's Sum will be equal to n(n+$1$)/$2$

n(n+$1$)/$2$ + x (x is the number he missed)=800+x

I am no ware getting to the Ans.

> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem

Comment: You had a similar question just a second ago and I am suspicious you are taking a test right now and asking for help.

Comment: @REALyumdub No,Its not a test.But questions for practice.

Comment: You've posted very many question which consist primarily of a picture of a question. This isn't really up to the quality standards of the site - please try to learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can type your questions into the site.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Is the Image of the question or Ans not allowed?

Comment: @Jack It is strongly discouraged - it makes the site less searchable and creates an unnecessary obstacle to answerers. It also really doesn't demonstrate effort on the part of the asker. We generally *tolerate* it from new users, but making a habit of it is not likely to please the community.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Okay I will keep this mind next time.But typing the questions I feel lazy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here may be that Ramu missed "a number," so he only missed one.

Your formula "$ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} + x = 800 + x $" doesn't make sense, the formula on the left in n assumes he consecutively counted numbers and then forgot x. And for the record, x gets removed from both sides in one step.

Let's do this instead: If Ramu only missed one number, then there must be an upper bound on the amount of numbers he was counting to, since if he counted to say 1000, then missing one number would be far above 800, no matter what the number was! Similarly, if the sum was less than 800, he would certainly not have missed a number.

Let $ S(n) = \dfrac{(n)(n + 1)}{2}$

Trying a few values gives us
$$ n = 30 \implies S = \dfrac{(30)(31)}{2} = 465  << 800$$
$$ n = 40 \implies S = \dfrac{(40)(41)}{2} = 820 > 800 $$

This actually looks like Ramu missed 20: But how is that confirmation?

Note that

$$ S(39) = S(40) - 40 = 780 $$
$$ S(41) = S(40) + 41 = 861 $$

Note that if Ramu missed one number calculating to 861, he could only go as low as missing the biggest number, 41, and that is 820 which is too big. On the other hand, if Ramu was summing the first 39 numbers, missing none would still be below 800. So Ramu must have been trying to sum each number from 1 to 40, and since the real answer is 20 above what he was trying to get to, he must have missed 20. **The answer is (B).**

This is kind of a cheesy way of doing the problem, there may be a better way where a formula is solved. But it is a valid argument.

Note that a lot of strange problems like these can be solved by showing the case above is too big and the case below is too small. If this is for some kind of competition, consider proofs where you can show a formula that must be a square is too big or too small in certain cases and prove all the values it is a square. This kind of reasoning is great for competitive situations, where the problem is strange and time is an issue.